# Initiate immediate phone call with react native on expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to initiate an immediate phone call without the middleware dialog.
I've used the `Linking.openUrl()` but it didn't work.

react-native-immediate-phone-call does that but it requires linking which isn't possible with `expo`. 
What can I do?

Answer (score 11):

You can use `Linking`. Import that by `import * as Linking from "expo-linking"`.

Then use `openURL` function where you use as argument `tel` instead `http`.

Similar like:

`Linking.openURL('tel:+12 XXX XXX XXX')` where X is any digit.

Hope that was helpful ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
import * as Linking from "expo-linking";
```

Then you can directly link to phone call like

```
 Linking.openURL(`tel:${phoneNumber}`);
```

There are other schemes also mentioned in the docs like mailto etc

> https://docs.expo.io/guides/linking/?redirected

Answer (score 0):

use react native phone call which can be installed from npm,,visit https://snack.expo.dev/@aboutreact/example-to-call-from-app-in-react-native on how to use the library

Answer (score 0):

```
 import {Linking, Platform } from 'react-native'

const onCallMobilePhone = async (phoneNumber: number) => {
    
    if(Platform.OS === 'android') {
      Linking.openURL(`tel:${phoneNumber}`);
      return;
    }
    
    if(Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      Linking.openURL(`telprompt:${phoneNumber}`)
      return;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Haven't ever felt the need to use expo, but [Linking is mentioned in their docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/linking/) and should work just fine.

You will probably need to test on a real device though, as I don't believe it will work in the iOS emulator. I do think it works on Android simulators, but I can't remember for sure.

Comment: Linking phone calls doesn't make the call, but just open up the phone screen with the number inside.

Answer (score -5):

You will have to use a react native project without expo or eject expo to use this module, as it is a native module and expo in my opinion is basically for learning.

So you will have to use it in a react native project created without expo

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I  believe Expo is the only way you can share projects with clients or users without publishing or building then having them manually install an APK.  So I wouldn't say it's just "for learning".

Comment: I dont' think it's just for learning, it's a quick way to get productive.